# Not reading all binary data from file

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qbytearray

In a project, I need to read binary data from a file and decompress using `gzip`. Problem is that `QFile::readAll()` does not actually read all bytes nor report any error.

Here's my code:

```
QFile ifile("/tmp/currentAlmanac.gz");
qDebug() << "File Size:" << ifile.size();

ifile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray data = ifile.readAll();
ifile.close();
qDebug() << "Almanac Size:" << data.size();
```

The output is:

> File Size: 78637
>   Almanac Size: 78281

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

There is plenty of free RAM.

Specs: Qt5.10 on Ubuntu16.04

Comment: Did you try to validate the contents of the file? The file size on disk and its actual bytes may be different depending on file system, disk compression, etc.

Comment: @Azeem I need to decompress it and the original file decompression works, whereas the QByteArray lacks some data. I've tried downloading the almanac from nasa again, decompressing and compressing again. I'm 99.9% sure the content is fine.

Comment: Lack some data? How did you verify this?

Comment: md5sum were different. However now I've switched between work and hobby sessions in QtCreator and this reinitialized the project and voila It's working. No change in the code! Size and md5sum is now the same. Decompress routine  Not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to read binary data from a file

I don't have a lot of experience with Qt, but it's easy enough to read large binary files into memory, then you can pass that into `gzip` to decompress. You could try something like this.  Use a container like `std::deque` to store the file in memory since it's large and doesn't need to be allocated in contiguous space like a `std::vector` does.

```
// set the chunk size to be the maximum I/O unit for your machine*
const size_t chunk_size = static_cast<size_t>(32768);
std::deque<uint8_t> bytes;  // store the whole file
std::vector<uint8_t> chunk(chunk_size, 0);  // temporary file chunk

std::ifstream dataFile;
dataFile.open( fileName.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary );

if ( dataFile.is_open() )
{
    // read entire file large chunks at a time
    while ( dataFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&chunk[0]),
                          chunk.size()) ||
            dataFile.gcount() )
    {
        // append each chunk to our data store
        bytes.insert(bytes.end(),
                     chunk.begin(),
                     chunk.begin() + dataFile.gcount());
    }

    dataFile.close();  // close the file when we're done
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to create file stream on ->" << fileName << "<-" << std::endl;
}
```